# How is it possible to install JRE on Ubuntu 11.04?

Tags: ubuntu, java, jre

I have searched widely for an answer to this, but I couldn't find anything that would work. I currently have JRE version 1.6.0_26 (which I suspect is 6u26) however I want to upgrade it to the latest version (u31?). I can't use `apt-get` because the repository isn't there, so how could I install it another way?

Comment: Of the methods you found, what have you tried and what didn't work for you?

Comment: Installing from a PPA repository (which only installed update 26 for me) and enabling the universe repository in the package manager.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its actually really easy, just download the bin file and execute it from the terminal (CD to the folder that it is in, then do ./.bin). Im not an expert with Ubuntu but its worth a try. Then move the exported files to your home folder or anywhere else and to run a java application, simply cd to the java directory and do ./java -jar .jar or whatever you wanna execute. Again, I have only done this once and can barely remember the steps. Excuse me if im wrong and there is probably a better, permanent way where you dont always have to run it from terminal and you can just double click a jar file to run it.

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jre
```

then

```
sudo apt-get install icedtea6-plugin
```

or

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ferramroberto/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install sun-java6-jre sun-java6-plugin sun-java6-fonts
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to the [Java](http://www.java.com/en/download/installed.jsp) site and check your installed version. Then you will get a link to download the latest version (including linux) along with detailed instructions to install.